Azure AD B2C UI customization with React
I want to customise the Azure AD B2C UI for a React application. I would like to investigate the possibilities of utilising <div id="api"></div> to accomplish ui customisation. The id=api should come from any of the react component.
The test app is created and deployed but Azure AD form fields are not visible in react component.
console error


You can't interfere with the div "api".
That's reserved for the B2C login screen, which is a web view.
You can do this.
